# How to clear airflow history of runs

Tags: airflow

I have an airflow setup.
Some dags run very frequently (~ every 15 min) generating quite a bit of history.

I would like to automatically delete these successfull runs if they are a week old or so.

Any ideas how I can set this?

I've been looking into doing this via the terminal, however this doesn't seem to work.

```
d=`date -d 'last week' +%Y-%m-%d`
#d=`date -d 'yesterday' +%Y-%m-%d`
echo $d
airflow clear r_calc_daemon -e $d
```

However the clear command does not seem to clearing up anything.
In the gui there is a delete button for the runs.
But you can imagine I have to push a lot to clean it up like this.

any tips doing this? I guess this is problem a lot of people encounter?

Comment: [`clairvoyant` guys](https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-maintenance-dags/blob/master/db-cleanup/airflow-db-cleanup.py) have published it; but this one cleans up history of all DAGs / tables; so you'll have to modify it as per your requirements